# how to use directive scope variable inside controller in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on `ionic framework`....i wanted to use directive scope variable inside controller? tried different options or answers told in `stack overflow` but none is working for me...so i am putting this question once again.

Here is my code:

```
.directive('simpleCaptcha', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { valid: '=' },
        template: '<input ng-model="a.value" ng-show="a.input" style="width:2em; text-align: center;"><span ng-hide="a.input">{{a.value}}</span>&nbsp;{{operation}}&nbsp;<input ng-model="b.value" ng-show="b.input" style="width:2em; text-align: center;"><span ng-hide="b.input">{{b.value}}</span>&nbsp;=&nbsp;{{result}}',
        controller: function($scope) {

            var show = Math.random() > 0.5;

            var value = function(max){
                return Math.floor(max * Math.random());
            };

            var int = function(str){
                return parseInt(str, 10);
            };

            $scope.a = {
                value: show? undefined : 1 + value(4),
                input: show
            };
            $scope.b = {
                value: !show? undefined : 1 + value(4),
                input: !show
            };
            $scope.operation = '+';

            $scope.result = 5 + value(5);

            var a = $scope.a;
            var b = $scope.b;
            var result = $scope.result;

            var checkValidity = function(){
                if (a.value && b.value) {
                    var calc = int(a.value) + int(b.value);
                    $scope.valid = calc == result;
                } else {
                    $scope.valid = false;
                }
                $scope.$apply(); // needed to solve 2 cycle delay problem;
            };


            $scope.$watch('a.value', function(){    
                checkValidity();
            });

            $scope.$watch('b.value', function(){    
                checkValidity();
            });



        }
    };
});
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function($scope, $ionicConfig, $http, $ionicPopup, $ionicModal) {
alert($scope.valid);
});
```

Comment: you can assign using `$parent` directly, i.e `$scope.$parent.value = $scope.value` in directive.

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Comment: here is my html code :<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">   
   <simple-captcha valid="captchaValid"></simple-captcha>
    <br><br>
    <div>valid: {{captchaValid}}</div>   
 <script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>    
  <button ng-click="show();">Click</button></ion-content>

</ion-view>

Comment: not working @sravan

Comment: is directive is used in the view of `DashboardCtrl`

Comment: yes ....simple-captcha is my directive

Comment: you should get the `captchaValid` as `false` in controller. what are you getting currently?

Comment: yes...m getting false

Comment: so according to the cuurent code its working fine. let me explain.

Comment: yes everything is working fine....i want on the click of button "click", get true or false in the alert..

Comment: try  `if ($scope.a.value && $scope.b.value)` in if condition and  `$scope.valid = calc == $scope.result;`,try directly using scope and check the result.

Comment: what is inside `show` method?

Comment: getting the same result....not getting the true or false in alert.

Comment: show method contains alert : $scope.show = function() {
                   alert($scope.valid);
               };

Comment: use `captchaValid` in controller `$scope.show = function() { alert($scope.captchaValid); }`

Comment: tried....same issue

Comment: try using `$scope` in `watch` function too.

Comment: if i add $scope in watch function then the captcha not work.